# ul li vertical menu using css

Tags: jquery, css

I need a vertical ul li menu fixed width. 
When window resize if li is hidden it will show like a drop down.
For example chrome development tool menu bar.
 Please anyone help me how to make it?

Comment: Can you show what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you understand that a well. To determine changing menu i use media queries, below is example of code. If You need any help, just write to me.

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>  
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS CODE**

```
body {
    width:400px;
}
.menu {
    width: 100px;
}
ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
ul li a {
    display:block;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    color: #999;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
    border-top: 1px solid #999;
    text-decoration: none;

}
ul li:first-child {
    border: none;
}
ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;

}
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 600px) {
    .menu {
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        background: #08c9a2 url('http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cc_mono_icon_set/blacks/32x32/list_bullets.png') no-repeat scroll 50% 50%;
    }
    .menu ul {
        display:none;
    }
    .menu:hover ul {
        display:block;
    }.menu:hover {
        width: 100px;
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/4nBHf/2/

Comment: Hi Bartek Bielawa, In above example you have used horizontal menu. I need vertical menu. Also when resize the window each li step by step moving to drop down. For example chrome developer tool menu.